How to get response with Nones when using the multiprocessing library on Python?
I'm using the multiprocessing package for Python to parallelize 2 functions. Each of those functions return a dictionary that can have None as value for some keys, and when that happens I'm getting this error

Error in multiprocessing my function: Error sending result: <Output of my function> Reason: 'TypeError("'NoneType' object is not callable")'

However, if I run this code, everything works correctly
import multiprocessing
def function1(param1):
        return {'a': param1, 'b': None}

def function2(param2):
    return {'c': param2, 'd': None}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        a = 3
        future_1 = pool.apply_async(function1, (3,))
        future_2 = pool.apply_async(function2, [a])
        result_1 = future_1.get()
        result_2 = future_2.get()
        
    print(result_1)
    print(result_2)


Any idea what kind of issues could be the cause of that error?

you posted a code that you say it works perfectly. You need to post the code that causes the error you mention, so we can reproduce it.

Somewhere in your code you will probably have something that's equivalent to None()

I know @Cincinnatus but that one comes from an endpoint in my application, I can't share it without sharing my entire application

A debugging step is to eliminate unnecessary code and make a [mcve]. Often, you’ll find the problem before needing to post. We can’t help you without code that produces the problem, other than predicting the problem will be a form of None().
